# Why the camera is not loading in spyder?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am doing a project based on image processing. In the project I uses the camera to detect and classify images. But the problem is sometimes the camera screen is blank. But sometimes it might come. What is the problem. Not only that whenever camera is showing, the image is very lagged and slow and stuck. How to fix this problem. I have attached the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvlAu.png)

So please give me the solution. Thanks

The code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model


#############################################

frameWidth = 640         # CAMERA RESOLUTION
frameHeight = 480
brightness = 180
threshold = 0.75         # PROBABILITY THRESHOLD
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

##############################################

# SETUP THE VIDEO CAMERA
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10, brightness)

# IMPORT THE TRAINED MODEL
#pickle_in = open("modeleff.p", "rb")  ## rb = READ BYTE
#model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

model = load_model("my_efficientnet_model.h5")

# Load the PyTorch model from the pickle file, specifying map_location=torch.device('cpu')
#with open("model_trained.p", "rb") as pickle_in:
#    model = torch.load(pickle_in, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))


def grayscale(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return img

def equalize(img):
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    return img

def preprocessing(img):
    img = grayscale(img)
    img = equalize(img)
    img = img / 255
    return img

def getClassName(classNo):
    # Define your class names here
    class_names = ['Speed Limit 20 km/h', 'Speed Limit 30 km/h', 'Speed Limit 50 km/h', 'Speed Limit 60 km/h', 'Speed Limit 70 km/h', 
                   'Speed Limit 80 km/h', 'End of Speed Limit 80 km/h', 'Speed Limit 100 km/h', 'Speed Limit 120 km/h', 'No passing', 
                   'No passing for vehicles over 3.5 metric tons', 'Right-of-way at the next intersection', 'Priority road', 'Yield', 
                   'Stop', 'No vehicles', 'Vehicles over 3.5 metric tons prohibited', 'No entry', 'General caution', 
                   'Dangerous curve to the left', 'Dangerous curve to the right', 'Double curve', 'Bumpy road', 'Slippery road', 
                   'Road narrows on the right', 'Road work', 'Traffic signals', 'Pedestrians', 'Children crossing', 
                   'Bicycles crossing', 'Beware of ice/snow', 'Wild animals crossing', 'End of all speed and passing limits', 
                   'Turn right ahead', 'Turn left ahead', 'Ahead only', 'Go straight or right', 'Go straight or left', 'Keep right', 
                   'Keep left', 'Roundabout mandatory', 'End of no passing', 'End of no passing by vehicles over 3.5 metric tons']
    return class_names[classNo]

# Set the size of the displayed window
cv2.namedWindow("Result", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Result", 800, 600)  # Adjust the width and height as needed

while True:
    # READ IMAGE
    success, imgOrignal = cap.read()

    # PROCESS IMAGE
    img = np.asarray(imgOrignal)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
    img = preprocessing(img)
    cv2.imshow("Processed Image", img)
    img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "CLASS: ", (20, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "PROBABILITY: ", (20, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # PREDICT IMAGE
    predictions = model.predict(img)
    classIndex = np.argmax(predictions)
    probabilityValue = np.amax(predictions)

    if probabilityValue > threshold:
        cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(classIndex) + " " + str(getClassName(classIndex)), (120, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(round(probabilityValue * 100, 2)) + "%", (180, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow("Result", imgOrignal)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: please edit your post to include the code that you have tried so far

Comment: Does this only happen when you run the code in Spyder and not if you run it from a command line?

Comment: this happens with pycharm also. I have included my code @nekomatic

Comment: So it doesn't look like a Spyder problem. What happens if you leave out the classification code for now, i.e. everything after `cv2.imshow("Processed Image", img)` until the `waitKey` line?

Comment: @nekomatic the result is same when I commented the codes you mentioned above. Is it the problem of Graphics processing? I have RTX 2050. But I don't know whether it is used in python?

Comment: OK so the slowdown is not due to the model prediction step. I can't help you further on this one sorry, except to suggest starting again with the simplest possible capture/display loop with the least possible processing and add your code gradually until you find the cause of the issue.